# 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' can not be casted to 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' on remote machine, but works locally

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am getting the error when trying from a server (deployed the same code on the server):

> `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'`

But when I am trying to use the same code from my local machine, it is not giving error.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
```

Any idea guys what could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry it has our server details and our admin credentials.But the uri is the same while accessing from local or from the server.

Comment: then give an example like "http[s]://foo.com/bar" or "c:/my/app"...

Comment: @marc: it was https problem, when i changed it to use http it started workin again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084108/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-net-filewebrequest-to-type-system-net-ht)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URI being passed in is not an `http` URI -- it's either just a path or a `file` URI.  Ensure the URI starts with `http:`.  If it's a relative URI, you'll need to make it absolute.

Comment: I was using https and that was the problem and when i changed it to use http it started working.

Answer (score 3):

`WebRequest` is the type returned by `WebRequest.Create()` factory method, and is an **abstract** type.

According to the protocol recognized in the URL string, it returns you a valid subclass, like `FileWebRequest` or `FtpWebRequest`.

The problem in your code is that you are trying to create a request for a local file (file://) protocol, so the factory returns `FileWebRequest`, but you are forcing the code to think it's are remote HTTP URL. Simply **wrong**.

This explains the fact that it works only with remote and not local files

Comment: I would differ on the statement that it is "simply wrong". Consider the use case of using FTPS (explicit) to send a local file. Seems to me, that framework should not be dictating my implementation.

Comment: How do you suggest is the better way to do it. I am trying to use a file on the local machine.