# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm getting the above error when trying to test on upload to FTP. But when I'm trying run this code from my local machine, it is giving error. Kindly advise.

Here my code below :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var yourListOfFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(filepath);

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (string filePath in yourListOfFilePaths)
            {
                zip.AddFile(filePath);    // FILE PATH LOCATION / WHICH FOLDER FILES YOU WANTED TO ZIP
                zip.Password = "abc1234"; // CHANGE YOUR PASSWORD HERE 
            }
            zip.Save(ZipPath + "\\Batch_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".zip");

            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.bitrix24.com/" + "\\Batch_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".zip");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("jayden@bitrix24.com", "abc123");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(ZipPath + "\\Batch_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".zip");
            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.bitrix24.com/"
                              + "\\Batch_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".zip");
```

Is your problem. You're sending an address which starts with "http" instead of "ftp.

Change your URL:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.bitrix24.com/" + 
                                "\\Batch_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyy") + ".zip");
```

Comment: i got this error when i amend and run it : 
The requested FTP command is not supported when using HTTP proxy.

Comment: @JaydenNg Try settings `request.Proxy = null`

Comment: this request.Proxy put before stream?

Comment: Thanks. but it encounter error with : 
Unable to connect to the remote server. is that a issue on the code? where i set request.Proxy = null;

Comment: Are you defining any proxies to connect? Because that means the server is unavailable.